Application.properties boolean defined value not used in bean
I have a bean class that I want to load a boolean value that is defined in the application.properties file of a springboot app. This is my application.properties file:
APP_CONTAINERIZED_VALUE=true

My class is annotated as @Component and uses this value like so:
@Value("${APP_CONTAINERIZED_VALUE:false}")
private boolean APP_CONTAINERIZED;

When I try yo run the spring server I get this exception:
Caused by: Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'APP_CONTAINERIZED_VALUE' in value "${APP_CONTAINERIZED_VALUE}"

Am I doing anything wrong? I have checked other similar posts but nothing seems to work for me.
Thanks in advance

Not sure upercase is working here. Try app.containerized.value.

Check if the property file is located in a directory supported by Spring. Usually it is the root of the classpath.
Here is the long list of the possible locations:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.13.RELEASE/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html
If you property file is inside of the jar-package, validate that it is really there. It is possible, you have a broken maven configuration and the file is copied into a wrong subfolder.
You can add the file with any name and location to you configuration manually. Like this:
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")

